# Position legend on left/right of fieldset

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, fieldset

I would like to create an effect that looks similar to:

```
____________________
|                  |
h                  |
e                  |
l                  |
l                  |
o                  |
|__________________|
```

when given an HTML snippet that looks like:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend> Hello </legend>
</fieldset>
```

I know we can create effects that looks like:

```
_________hello______
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|__________________|
```

and can use the `text-align` property to realign the *hello* text to the left, right or center.

I also know we can place legend text inside the `fieldset` by using the `float` property, and we can place a legend outside the `fieldset` border ([How do I place the legend outside the fieldset border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29828346/how-do-i-place-the-legend-outside-the-fieldset-border))

But it seems like there's no support / quick method for placing the legend text along the `fieldset` border.
I came across the `align` property for legends, but it doesn't work on HTML5 (https://html.com/attributes/legend-align/).

Comment: Please read the [tour] _"Don't ask about...

    Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_

Comment: writing-mode  can do  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/rNyRBPJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does not seem to be a plain-HTML way to do it. In the mean time, try this absolute positioning solution:

```css
legend {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: -7px;
    width: 1ch;
    word-break: break-all;
    background-color: white;
}
fieldset{
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend> Hello </legend>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I've tried using the align property to no avail. It seems it was deprecated in newer browser versions.

Comment: @razor_chk The `align` property does nothing in the example. I've removed it so as not to cause confusion.

Comment: Somehow, the `position` property for my `legend` is relative to the body's position and not the fieldset's position. Could there be any reason why this is happening?

Comment: @razor_chk I've updated my answer. Try it again

Comment: This seems good thanks